# Javascript placement of an external file

Tags: javascript, file, external

I have HTMl document which is radio buttons, and a function which is in external file filename.js
and I am using  inside .
it is down right correct in every possible way, copy cat from book, but it will not work when 
executing html file. I have placed both .html file and filename.js file into new folder only two files inside it. what seems to be the problem here, I like some suggestions.

authorx.

Comment: Could you post some code as well?

Comment: Please post some code samples

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say exactly without seeing some code, but the standard way of executing a separate javascript file from an html file is to use the script tag. More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

In your case, the tag would look something like

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Radio Button </title>
<script type= "text/javascript" src = "radio_plane.js" >
</script>

<body>
<h4> Cessna single-engine airplane description </h4>
<form id="myform" action="">
<p>
<label><input type="radio" name="planebutton" value="152" onclick="action(152);" />
                Model 152 </label>
                <br />
<label><input type="radio" name="planebutton" value="172" onclick="action(172);" />
                Model 172 (Skyhawk)</label>
            <br />
<label><input type="radio" name="planebutton" value="182" onclick="action(182);" />
                Model 182</label>
            <br />
<label><input type="radio" name="planebutton" value="210" onclick="action(210);" />
            Model 210 (Centurian) </label>
            <br />
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
and javascript file


function action(plane)
{
switch(plane)
{
case 152:
alert("A small two-place airplane for flight training");
break;
case 172:
alert("The Smaller of two four-plane airplanes");
break;
case 182:
alert("The larger of two four-place airplanes");
break;
case 210:
alert("A six-place high-performance airplane");
break;
default:
alert("Error in JavaScript function planeChoice");
break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Code samples should be in your original question, not in a separate answer. Consider editing your original question to include this code.